# Grothendieck Topology on the Category of Elements

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

We are given a site $(C, J)$ for a small category $C$ and a Grothendieck topology $J$. If $F\in Sh(C, J)$, we take the natural topology $J_F$ on its category of elements $el(F)$ induced by $J$. I am wondering if $Sh(C,J)_{/F}\simeq Sh(el(F),J_F)$?

Comment: Have you had any problems defining the obvious functors or showing they give equivalences? (Given a sheaf $X\to^f F$ and an object $(c,x)$ of $el(F)$ with $x\in F(C)$, write $\bar X(c,x)=f^{-1}(x)$. In the other direction given a sheaf $Y$ on elements of $F$ define $\underline{Y}(c)$ as the disjoint union of $Y(c,x)$ over all $x\in F(c)$, and map $\underline{Y}(c)$ to $F(c)$ by sending elements of $Y(c,x)$ to $x$.)