# category of sheaves over an object

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I'm looking for a solution of exercice III.8 (b) in Maclane and Moerdijk's book $\textit{Sheaves in Geometry and Logic}$. Where I can find such a solution ? Or can someone describe the topology J' that makes the equivalence $Sh(\mathcal{C},J)/P \cong Sh(\int_{\mathcal{C}} P,J') $ true ?

Best

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129832/5191).

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. The equivalence is clear.